# Advice on implementing workflow, involving opening new case for contact created by profile

Tags: profile, civicase, civicrm-spark

I would like to implement the following workflow: a "potential church volunteer (PCC)" fills in his or her details in a profile hyper-linked to from a WordPress website. This creates a contact in CiviCRM (hosted on a different server) and opens a "case" with a series of activities which must be applied to the contact over time (some immediately, some in 1 week, and so on).

So far, I've implemented this by setting up the profile so that it assigns new contacts to the group "PCC Unopened Case". This then requires a member of staff to go into CiviCRM, move the contact to a new group "PCC Opened Case", remove them from the original group, and open an already built case called "PCC Workflow" for that contact. That's a rather manual solution, and the charity I'm volunteering for doesn't love it. I'm aware of CiviRules, though I've not used it because it's currently not supported on the Spark-hosted solution I'm trialling. (By the way, the support provided by Spark is really outstanding.) Is there another less manual -- perhaps even standard pattern -- for implementing such a process (submit details -> open case -> follow through on activities). Many thanks, Patrick.

Comment: I'm not sure what spark supports but it sounds like that's going to limit the possibilities a bit. Does it support lab.civicrm.org/extensions/caldera-civicrm/ since that might be another option.

Comment: It sounds like the sort of process that would we tend to approach using Drupal Views and Webforms as that gives more flexibility than directly in CiviCRM

Comment: Thank you, both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read that correctly, your WordPress site just has a link to the form on CiviCRM?  (ie the form is not directly on the website?)  If so, that gives you a few more options.

Your simplest option would be to create your form using the FormBuilder core extension instead of using a profile and have it create the case.  That should be available on Spark.

Alternatively using your profile approach, you could ask about CiviRules. Spark is intended as kind of 'starter edition' and doesn't allow arbitrary extensions.  However, the exact set of extensions evolves and it is worth asking whether it would be possible to add that.  (Given what CiviRules can do, I think that is unlikely - but no harm asking.)

Another option would be the [Form Processor](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor) extension, but again that may not be available on Spark.

There are various ways this could be implemented, but it's certainly possible.  Ask if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In very recent CiviCRM versions (around 5.54?), Form Builder can now open cases. I have not personally tested it, but was told it works. CiviCRM Spark is currently on CiviCRM 5.55.

So instead of using a profile, a form created with Form Builder should be able to open the case correctly for you.

CiviRules might help for things such as sending notifications automatically.

And finally, SearchKit can replace what traditionally Views did, and is supported by CiviCRM out of the box (and CiviCRM Spark).

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful and overlaps somewhat with recommendations given below.